# Failed to load the native TensorFlow runtime. Downloaded anaconda 3-5.2

Tags: python, python-3.x, tensorflow, keras

I installed  anaconda 3-5.2 from the anaconda install archive and I can't seem to get tensorflow working. When I try to import it this is the error message I get. I recently updated brew and deleted anaconda and reinstalled it also.

```
ImportError: Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/Users/admin/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/pywrap_tensorflow.py", line 41, in <module>
from tensorflow.python.pywrap_tensorflow_internal import *
File "/Users/admin/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/pywrap_tensorflow_internal.py", line 28, in <module>
_pywrap_tensorflow_internal = swig_import_helper()
File "/Users/admin/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/pywrap_tensorflow_internal.py", line 24, in swig_import_helper
_mod = imp.load_module('_pywrap_tensorflow_internal', fp, pathname, description)
File "/Users/admin/usr/local/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/imp.py", line 243, in load_module
return load_dynamic(name, filename, file)
File "/Users/admin/usr/local/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/imp.py", line 343, in load_dynamic
return _load(spec)
ImportError: dlopen(/Users/admin/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/_pywrap_tensorflow_internal.so, 10): Library not loaded: @rpath/libcublas.8.0.dylib
Referenced from: /Users/admin/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/_pywrap_tensorflow_internal.so
Reason: image not found
```

Failed to load the native TensorFlow runtime.

See https://www.tensorflow.org/install/install_sources#common_installation_problems

for some common reasons and solutions.  Include the entire stack trace
above this error message when asking for help.

Answer (score 1):

You need to install using `conda install tensorflow` so that the cuda and cudnn libraries are install.